# I want to allow, as an @Input of a component, only keys that have string values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular12

I have a generic component that accepts an array of object of type T and a string that is a key of T. The purpose of this component is to filter the array of objects based on a character in the alphabet but to do so I need the given input key to have a string value.
Here's some sample code:

```
@Input() data: T[];
@Input() key: keyof T;

function filterByChar(char: string) {
    return this.data.filter(el => el[this.key] === char);
}
```

This does not work because `el[this.key]` might not be a string.

Is it possible to restrict `key` to be a key of object T that have string values only?

Here's a [link to stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dhbhri?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/filter-by/filter-by.component.ts)

EDIT:
The `@Input() key` has a restriction, only keys of T are allowed. I want to allow only keys of T that have string values (at compile time if possible).

**EDIT 2**:
Suppose the actual type of T is something like this:

```
interface Person {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  address: Address;
}
```

When you call my component

`<app-filter-by [data]="someData" [key]="XXXX"></app-filter-by>`

I want to enforce that only keys of T of type string are allowed.
In this example only **name** and **email** should be allowed.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but wouldn't you just filter with a predicate like: `(typeof el[this.key] === 'string') && el[this.key].includes(char)` ?

Comment: The problem is not the function, I want to enforce, at compile time, that the @Input ```key``` should be any key of object T that have a string value

Comment: What do you expect T to be..?

Comment: Check Edit 2, I made an example of what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

try some of these:

```
return this.data.filter(el => (el as any)[this.key] === char);

return this.data.filter(el => (($any)el)[this.key] === char);

return this.data.filter(el => ( el[this.key] as unknown as keyof T === char ));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering but I think I did not explain well what I want to achieve. I want to restrict, at compile time, the keys of T that have string values so that I can be sure that the filter predicate (```el[this.key] === char``` ) makes sense